# streaming excel to aws s3 using aws lambda

Tags: javascript, excel, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

i am getting some data from db, creating an excel sheet streaming  and upload to aws s3 using aws lambda

```
const date = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
        const fileName = `reports/${date}/applications.xlsx`;

        const passThrough = new stream.PassThrough();
        const workbook = new ExcelJS.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter({
            stream: passThrough,
            useStyles: true
        });

        const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Applications');
        const headers = Object.keys(applications[0]);
        worksheet.addRow(headers);

        for (let application of applications) {
            const row = headers.map(header => {
                if (hyperlinkHeaders.includes(header)) {
                    return { text: application[header], hyperlink: application[header] };
                }
                return application[header];
            });
            worksheet.addRow(row);
        }
        await workbook.commit();

        const uploadCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
            Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: fileName,
            Body: passThrough,
            ContentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        });
        await s3.send(uploadCommand);
```

but i am geeting some errors. cant figure out what i am doing
START RequestId:  Version: $LATEST
2023-10-26T08:31:47.125Z        ERROR   NotImplemented: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented
at throwDefaultError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:8:22)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:18:39
at de_PutObjectCommandError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restXml.js:5721:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24
at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/awsAuthMiddleware.js:14:20
at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46
at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-flexible-checksums/dist-cjs/flexibleChecksumsMiddleware.js:58:20
at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:7:26
at async Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.mjs:104:13) {
'$fault': 'client',
'$metadata': {
httpStatusCode: 501,
requestId: '',
extendedRequestId: '',
cfId: undefined,
attempts: 1,
totalRetryDelay: 0
},
Code: 'NotImplemented',
Header: 'Transfer-Encoding',

Comment: Solved it
const uploadCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
                Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
                Key: fileName,
                Body: passThrough,
                ContentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                ContentLength: passThrough.readableLength
            });
need to add content lenght

Answer (score 0):

const uploadCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
Key: fileName,
Body: passThrough,
ContentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
ContentLength: passThrough.readableLength
});

adding ContentLength: passThrough.readableLength solved the issue